# Does $2x=0$ imply $x=0$ in a field with characteristic not equal 2.

Tags: field-theory, positive-characteristic

Let $F$ be a field with $char(F)\neq 2$. If $2x=0$ with $x\in F$, can we 
get $x=0$?

Comment: That'd be a yes

Comment: All fields are integral domains.  Integral domains have no nonzero zero divisors.

Comment: $2$ is invertible in any field of characteristic $\not=2$, more or less by definition.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, just multiply both sides of the equation $2x = 0$ by the inverse of $2$ to get $x = 0$.